# how to customize html for django form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I am using an html template for my website, and wants to collect information to my django backend. Specifically, I want to return the value of email address from this part of the code

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" value="" style="height: 30px; width: 250px; border: 2px solid grey; padding: 7px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px;">
```

if i put `{{%form.email%}}` in to `value=""`, it'll write `<input id=` inside the box, and `">` outside of the box.

if I put `{{%form.email%}` behind  this part of html code, it will generate another box. But i only want to use this box.

How should i do it?

Comment: What do you want to customize on your form field? `HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')`?

Comment: I don't want to customize anything on `HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')`. That's another question, my bad. I want to customize the html code that creates the style of box i want from which I can return value generated by users to the backend form.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to generate a field by using a Django-Form Class. There you can also customize your entire field: For your example you would have to create a class like this in your forms.py

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form)
    email  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'email-input',
                                                            'placeholder': 'Email'})
```

You can also use

```
{'style': 'height: 30px; width: 250px; border: 2px solid grey; padding: 7px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px;'}
```

instead of `{'class': 'email-input'}` for your style, but it's usually better to use a css class.

The `email` in your class is basically your entire email field but it automatically generates a name and id so it's easier to use.

Now if you want the value of your field in the backend you have to do a GET or POST request (I think in this case POST). You will get the value by using the following pattern in the method in which you want to handle the recieved data: (works but not optimal) `field_value = request.POST.get('fieldname')` or even better as Daniel pointed out in the comments with `field_value = form.cleaned_data['fieldname']`.

So In your case it would be something like this: `email = form.cleaned_data['email']`. This will return the value that was typed into the field for later backend-use.

Comment: You were doing well until the last two paragraphs. The point of a form is that you should use it to access the posted data after validation, via `form.cleaned_data['fieldname']`, rather than accessing the request.POST data directly.

Comment: Thank you guys very much! it indeed works, for my testing page - but not on the real page. I think the code is basically same, but I don't know why the one on my real page just can't store value to the database.

Comment: Testing page code goes like: `<form action="/users/presignup/" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.email.errors }}
        
        <label for="id_email">Your email:</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" value="">
        </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>`

Comment: Real page code goes like: `<div class="register-wrap">
               <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.non_field_errors }} 
                <div class="form"> 
                {{ form.email.errors }}
                <input  name="email" type="text"  placeholder="Email" value="" style="height: 30px; width: 250px; border: 2px solid grey; padding: 7px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px;">
                <input type="submit" value="Learn More" class="button3"> 
                </div> 
                </form>
   </div>`

Comment: on the view side it was corrected as the way you said : `email=form.cleaned_data['email']`, and as I said it worked for the testing page